# Downloading all files in a directory with ftp command

Tags: windows, batch, ftp

I am trying to download all of the files in a directory using the FTP command on Windows (Windows Server 2012 R2). Here is what I am running from the ftp command:

```
open myurl.com
myusername
mypassword

cd directoryIwantonExternalServer
lcd directoryIwantonLocalmachine
binary

mget *.*
```

Everything seems to work fine until the last line, when running `mget *.*`. This results in no output for an indefinite period. I am only trying to transfer as a test two text files.

Comment: I don't think windows' ftp client is any good at all. Like it won't probably support passive mode either. If someone confirms it, the only workaround would be to use another FTP client or maybe create in the server an index file which contains the filenames to be downloaded.

Comment: I'm wanting to automate downloading files in a batch script eventually across multiple computers. This seems like it could be the easiest solution, as it's the most universal (doesn't require additional software, inc. PS).

Comment: Have you try to enter before mget the command prom?

Comment: Pressing enter to make a blank line before running mget worked. Thanks Romeo! Feel free to make it an answer and I will accept it. No clue why that worked...

Comment: @RomeoNinov 's answer works because you are essentially setting variables. Things like your user name, password, the paths to the servers -- those need to be set before calling the mget *.*. Otherwise, you get the result you are getting. Think of it like a "GO" is SQL Server. Some stuff needs to execute before the other commands will function.

Answer (score 0):

To get indications of the process of download from ftp server you can enter command `hash` after entering username and password. You can in general enter the command anywhere before sending command mget

To avoid interactive questions about downloading next file (based on wildcard) you can use command `prompt`. This command act as switch, first execution turn it off, next turn it on and so on

Comment: I'll be nice and not downvote you, but that doesn't seem right at all.  use "prompt off" to turn off interactivity.  Use "hash" to get the progress indicator like what you're referring to.

Comment: You are right, will correct my answer. And to clarify prompt command is a switch, first execution turn it off, next turn it on

Answer (score 0):

Once you've logged into your FTP server and have cd'd into the folder containing the files you wish to get in one go, you do this:

1. Disable prompt (it toggles)

```
prompt
```

2. use mget for multiple files

```
mget *.*
#or other wildcard patterns
mget *.gz
```